# DataSet changes not being persisted to database

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, persistence

I have a windows form with a number of data-bound fields relating to a client. Additionally, I have a DataGridView showing orders for the currently displayed client. This is achieved using the design-time Visual Studio controls (e.g. a project DataSet, BindingSources TableAdapters and a TableAdapterManager.

When loading the form to edit an existing client it is populated using a (custom) FillByID method on the ClientsTableAdapter to filter the DataSet to the single, relevant client. This loads their details into the client fields, and populates the orders DataGridView correctly.

Any changes I make to a client's orders (within the DataGridView) are persisted to the database when saving, however, none of the client detail fields are. They are editable, and show the correct details when loading, but no changes that are made are saved when the form is closed. I have tried two separate ways of persisting them now, the first being inline with the order saving:

```
this.Validate();
this.clientordersBindingSource.EndEdit();
this.clientsBindingSource.EndEdit();
this.clientordersTableAdapter.Update(projectDataSet.clientorders);
this.clientsTableAdapter.Update(projectDataSet.clients);
```

...and the second using the [multiple table example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4esb49b4(v=VS.80).aspx) on MSDN. Sadly, neither of these methods work with regards to the client details - although changes to client orders **are** persisted in both cases.

My clients table has the following structure:

```
refnumber, title, forename, surname, gender, dob, contactnumber
```

The clientsTableAdapter has the following CommandText strings for the DeleteCommand, InsertCommand, SelectCommand and UpdateCommand respectively:

```
DELETE FROM clients WHERE (refnumber = @Original_refnumber)
INSERT INTO clients (refnumber, title, forename, surname, gender, dob, contactnumber) VALUES (@refnumber, @title, @forename, @surname, @gender, @dob, @contactnumber)
SELECT refnumber, title, forename, surname, gender, dob, contactnumber FROM clients
UPDATE clients SET refnumber = @refnumber, title = @title, forename = @forename, surname = @surname, gender = @gender, dob = @dob, contactnumber = @contactnumber WHERE (refnumber = @Original_refnumber)
```

When saving, if I add a variable to capture the result of this line:

```
var res = this.clientsTableAdapter.Update(projectDataSet.clients);
```

- `projectDataSet.clients.Count == 1`
- `projectDataSet.clients.Rows[0].ItemArray` shows the modified fields.
- `projectDataSet.clients.Rows[0].RowState == Unchanged`
- `res == 0`

Please can anyone offer any hints? This has been driving me insane for days!

---

**UPDATE**

I recreated the form from scratch using the Visual Studio designer, then copied & pasted all the code from the original form. It now works. I guess something must have been wrong in the Designer.cs file with one of the datasources/databinding fields.

Thanks for the helpful debugging hints, ewall and Ladislav Mrnka.

Comment: Take a look at myTableAdapter.UpdateCmd.CommandText and post it here if needed.

Comment: TableAdapter.Update() returns an integer results with a count of the number of rows that were changed... if it's returning 0 then perhaps your EndEdit() is not applied on the correct (that is, currently active in-edit) item.

Comment: @ewall: That sounds like it could be it; I have multiple TableAdapters and BindingSources for a master-detail view on the form. How do I set the currently active source for an edit?

Comment: @ewall: I captured the return values and you are correct; the client (master) `Update()` returns 0 but the orders (detail) `Update()` returns 1.

Comment: To be safe, you could call EndEdit() on both sources...

Comment: Check that state of the row in clients table is set to modified. If not it will not call update. You can also run SQL profiler to see if update is executed. DataSet also has some auto generated class called TableManager or something like that which should be able to execute update on all tables (it works with all adapters) but we had some troubles with using it.

Comment: @Ladislav: Ahh. Calling `var state = projectDataSet.clients.Rows[0].RowState` just before the `TableAdapter.Update()` call results in the state `Unchanged`. Is this a databinding issue?

Comment: Probably yes. Also check if values in data set are changed.

Comment: `projectDataSet.clients.Rows[0].ItemArray` is showing the modified values (i.e. those from the bound fields on the form), so that means the DataSet is updated, right? Any ideas on the databinding issue? The fields are populated from the database fine, it's just going back the other way... :/

Answer (score 1):

What are you saving too for a datasource?  Second, make sure your tableadapters have valid update, insert, and delete commands.  I have had issues where they are not filled out even though the wizard said it had done it.

Comment: It is saving to a SQLite database using the System.Data.SQLite component. All the TableAdapters have valid commands.

Comment: Do you have the file as part of your project?  If so, is it set to copy to the output directory?  I believe I ran into a similar issue with Access.  The problem was that when I restarted the app it was blowing away my changes because it kept copying a clean version of the db over the one I had modified.  Just a thought.

Comment: Yes, the database is OK as changes to the other tables are saved correctly. It is only the clients table that won't save:/